# Is it ok to ask questions about being banned on meta stack overflow?

Tags: discussion, rules

From reading the faq, there does not seem to be much information on what is OK to talk about on meta Stack Overflow. If my question violates any of the rules here I will gladly delete it.

Right now I just got question banned from Stack Overflow and I really want to know why my question was a violation. Being new to this site I am not all to familiar with the ropes.

Sometimes the FAQ can't always explain every single detail of what exactly a violation is. I had a question related to banning. But before I ask, I just want to know if it's OK to ask that kind of question here.

Comment: You'd want to [take a look here.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/175248)

Comment: It is not forbidden per se to ask about question bans on Meta, but a mere *Why was I banned?* question gets usually closed as a duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997. I can see only a single question on your SO account. Do you have more accounts? Do you use a shared IP? Have you any deleted questions?

Comment: I understand that. I just want to know if it's ok to ask questions about how to get unbanned on meta stack overflow.

Comment: I had two other questions but both of them I deleted. One I deleted for getting bad reputation. The other I deleted in response to the ban even though I had no ideas what was wrong with it. The one thats still there could not be deleted and thats about all of them. And no, this is my only account.

Comment: The exact metrics are unknown to us mortals, but deleting questions make matters worse. You won't get much more information here on Meta then what is already written in the Meta post Makoto linked to.

Comment: You can flag one of your posts and ask a moderator to undleete your self-deleted posts so you can improve them

Comment: First of all is this question that I asked here a violation? Also is it possible to get unbanned?

Comment: No, asking this question is not a violation. Yes, it's possible to get unbanned. You have to improve (edit) your posts so that they get a better score (upvotes and/or undownvotes). If the overall score of your questions improves enough, you can ask questions again. Allegedly, answering questions (with good answers that get upvotes) helps too.

Comment: What about questions or answers that don't get any votes?

Comment: Those don't count against you, but improving them so they get upvotes *will* help you

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'm ready to work and earn that priviledge back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You were not likely block from asking questions based on one post. Question blocks are triggered automatically by the system based on a *history* of poor content — usually when most of your questions have been either down-voted or not voted on at all. The block simply says that we'd like you to work on your **existing** content before trying to post further.

To see why your content was not well received, start by reading through any comments left by users. If they are not clear (or absent), it is okay to leave your own comments asking for clarification. Work through the *original* post to improve it, when you can.

Next, I read through the advice offered by these links:

- [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers)
- [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

After all that, if you still do not understand the reasoning behind the voting, sure, it is okay to ask here.